# F test (joint significance) for two parameters

Tags: r, statistical-significance, garch, f-test

I want to test for the joint significance of two parameters (dcca1 and dccb1) estimated from a multivariate DCC GARCH model. does anyone know how to do it using R? any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: thank you very much I have upvoted.

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory, you may also accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the process described by the DCC-GARCH model does not exist [(McAleer, 2019)](https://repub.eur.nl/pub/115611/EI2019-13.pdf), there is no point in testing hypotheses about the parameters of such a nonexistant process (such as the hypothesis that both parameters are equal to zero). From Section 4 of the paper:

> <...> there is no likelihood function, and hence no derivatives that would enable the derivation of asymptotic properties for the Quasi-Maximum Likelihood Estimates (QMLE) of the estimated parameters. Therefore, **any statements regarding the purported “statistical signiﬁcance” of the estimated parameters are meaningless and lack statistical validity**. It follows that any empirical results based on the DCC estimates are fatally ﬂawed and lack statistical validity.

(emphasis is mine).

**References**

- McAleer, M. (2019). [What They Did Not Tell You About Algebraic (Non-) Existence, Mathematical (IR-) Regularity and (Non-) Asymptotic Properties of the Dynamic Conditional Correlation (DCC) Model](https://repub.eur.nl/pub/115611/EI2019-13.pdf). *Journal of Risk and Financial Management, 12*(2), 61.

Comment: It is interesting that this "deficiency" of the DCC-GARCH model is not acknowledge even among many academics. Do you know what academics are doing when applying the DCC-GARCH. Do they try bootstrapping to get a finite sample distribution? Or something else?

Comment: @JohanStaxJakobsen, No idea. I am also struggling with the notion of existence of a stochastic process and its need, as can be seen in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/407725/) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/407295/) question.